# Mapping from 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to use a 2-D array in C#, e.g:

```
string[,] a = new string[,]
{
    {"aunt", "AUNT_ID"},
    {"Sam", "AUNT_NAME"},
    {"clozapine", "OPTION"},
};
```

My requirement is that when I pass `"aunt"` to this array I want to get corresponding `AUNT_ID` from the 2-D array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, a `Dictionary<string, string>` would be better - and you can use a *collection initializer* to create it simply:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"ant", "AUNT_ID"},
    {"Sam", "AUNT_NAME"},
    {"clozapine", "OPTION"},
};
```

If you're confident that your key is in the dictionary, and you're happy for an exception to be thrown otherwise:

```
string value = dictionary[key];
```

or if it might not be:

```
string value;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
{
    // Use value here
}
else
{
    // Key wasn't in dictionary
}
```

If you really need to use an array, if you can change it to a multidimensional array (`string[][]`), you can use:

```
// Will throw if there are no matches
var value = array.First(x => x[0] == key)[1];
```

Or again to be more circumspect:

```
var pair = array.FirstOrDefault(x => x[0] == key);
if (pair != null)
{
    string value = pair[1];
    // Use value here
}
else
{
    // Key wasn't in dictionary
}
```

LINQ unfortunately doesn't work quite as well on rectangular arrays. It probably wouldn't be too hard to write a method to allow it to be treated "somewhat" like an array of arrays, admittedly...

Answer (score 2):

Use `Dictionary<string, string>` for that:

```
Dictionary<string, string> arr = new Dictionary<string, string>();
arr.Add("ant", "AUNT_ID");
arr.Add("Sam", "AUNT_NAME");
arr.Add("clozapine", "OPTION");

string k = arr["ant"]; // "AUNT_ID"
```

Comment: Note that using a collection initializer makes this code look much more like the originally-posted code.

Answer (score 1):

The best option for you is to use Dictionary, but if you still wants to use 2D array, you may try the following

```
    string[,] a = new string[,]
                    {
                        {"ant", "AUNT_ID"},
                        {"Sam", "AUNT_NAME"},
                        {"clozapine", "OPTION"},
                    };
    string search = "ant";
    string result = String.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++) //loop until the row limit
    {
        if (a[i, 0] == search)
        {
            result = a[i, 1];
            break; //break the loop on find 
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine(result); // this will display AUNT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks rather like you want a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> a = new Dictionary<string, string>();
a.Add("ant", "AUNT_ID");
a.Add("Sam", "AUNT_NAME");
a.Add("clozapine", "OPTION");

string s = a["ant"]; // gets "AUNT_ID"
```

---

To check if a key exists in the dictionary:

```
if (a.ContainsKey("ant")) {
  ...
}
```

Or:

```
string s;
if (a.TryGetValue("ant", out s)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: But in some case 'ant' is not in the Dictionary then, it should give me an exception

Answer (score -2):

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++){
    if (!String.Compare(a[i][0], string)){
        stored_string= a[i][1];
    }
}
```